# Can't get the size of a model attribute in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

This is my first project using jsp and I'm trying to build a table where each line looks a bit like this

[Here is a line of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnQu2.png)

In the last column (likes) there is currently only a button but i would like to display the number of likes next to it.

Here is my problem. When I try to use the jsp function length `${fn:length(mes.likes)}`

I get the following exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Problems calling function [fn:length]
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:606)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:482)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
```

I load all messages in the model from the **HomeController**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    IMessageService messageService;
    @GetMapping("/homepage")
    public String index(Model model) {
        List<MessageEntity> messages = messageService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("allMessages", messages);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Here is the **MessageEntity** class

```
public class MessageEntity{
    private int Id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date createdAt;
    private User createdBy;
    private List<LikeEntity> likes;
}
```

and finally, here is my table in the **index.jsp** file where I display the informations.

```
<table id="panneau">
    <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Emetteur</th>
            <th>Date/heure</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-black">
        <c:forEach var="mes" items="${allMessages}">
            <tr id="message${mes.id}">
                <td>
                    <div><b>${mes.title}</b></div>
                    <div>${mes.content}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${mes.anonymous}">
                            anonyme
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            ${mes.createdBy.firstName} ${mes.createdBy.lastName}
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${mes.createdAt}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>${fn:length(mes.likes)}</div>
                    <div><button class="btn btn-dark" id="like${mes.id}"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i></button></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I remove `${fn:length(mes.likes)}`, everything works fine, but I need a way to get to this information.

I have looked at other similar questions but none of them seemes to fix my problem.

By the way, I do have `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>` in the begining of the file

## EDIT

Here is the likeEntity class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;
/**
 * Created by owner on 18-05-07.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "likes", schema = "heroku_9efd0238a94d992")
public class LikeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "like_id", nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_dislike", nullable = true)
    private Boolean isDislike;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.REFRESH,
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "liked_by")
    private UserEntity likedBy;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.REFRESH,
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "liked_message") 
    private MessageEntity likedMessage;
    public LikeEntity() {
        this.setDislike(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you try and output it with only: `${mes.likes}`  What do you see then?

Comment: I get anothere error : `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: isep.project.web.entity.MessageEntity.likes, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: can you post your `LikeEntity` class?

Comment: I added the LikeEntity class to the post

Comment: well i can see why you might be getting an error then. I'm not really familiar with whatever technology you're using there. Why not create this likes entity in the same way you have created your message entity?

Comment: did you get all this data in controller?

Comment: @SanjayPatel you are right the problem come from there, if i try to get the like count in the controller, i get the same LazyInitializationException

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I used the same kind of anotations in both entities but didnt include them in the initial post to make it shorter

Comment: thank you for your help, I now know where to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclamer**: This is a workaround, not really a solution

I still don't know why the likes could not load lazily, but changing the fetchtype from lazy to eager seems to have done the trick...

I know this solution is not optimal. In my case, this workaround is suitable because it is only a school project so I will never have thousands of likes on a message.

If however, you work with a large set of data, I do not think this solution would be appropriate.